# How do i return the number of words in a resulting document to calculate the TF

Tags: php, tf-idf

I've been set the challenge of creating a basic text file search engine in PHP in a very limited time, having little to no previous programming knowledge its quite a task!

Here is what we have so far, it does manage to return the document((s) - if more than one with same amount) with the highest number of occurrences of a word.

Problem is the way we have done it does not (atleast not easily) allow us to calculate the TF-IDF score. The IDF is done, but we need to calculate the TF by getting the total number of words in the returned document, and that is what we are having problems with. The other problem is that it only returns the highest document, and we cannot get it to return a list of documents each with their score.... i.e. one document has the word "airline" in 3 times, two other documents have it once and they are forgotten and only the first is returned...

(there was also some problems with stripping symbols, but we worked around that, albeit a drawn out method...)

Here is what we have:

```
<?php
$starttime = microtime();
$startarray = explode(" ", $starttime);
$starttime = $startarray[1] + $startarray[0];

if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $searchWord = $_GET['search'];
}
else
{
    $searchWord = null;
}

?>
<html>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="searchbar">
        <h1>PHP Search</h1>
        <form name='searchform' id='searchform' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='get'>
          <input type='text' name='search' id='search' value='<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>' />
            <input type='submit' value='Search' />
        </form>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div><!-- close searchbar -->
    <?php


//path to directory to scan
$directory = "./files/";

//get all image files with a .txt extension.
$files = glob("" . $directory . "*.txt");
$fileList = array();
//print each file name
foreach($files as $file)
{
$fileList[] =  $file;
}
//$fileList;


        function indexFile($file){
            $filename = $file;
            $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
            $file_contents = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
            fclose($fp);

            $pat[0] = "/^\s+/";
            $pat[1] = "/\s{2,}/";
            $pat[2] = "/\s+\$/";
            $rep[0] = "";
            $rep[1] = " ";
            $rep[2] = "";

            $new_contents = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\s+]/", "", $file_contents);
            $new_contents = preg_replace($pat, $rep, $new_contents);

            //COMMON WORDS WERE HERE
            include "commonwords.php";

            $lines = explode("\n", $new_contents);
            $lines2 = implode(" ", $lines); //string
            $lines2 = strtolower($lines2);

            //echo $lines2 . "<br><br>";

            $words = explode(" ", $lines2); //array
            //$words = $lines;
            $useful_words = array_diff($words, $commonWords);
            $useful_words = array_values($useful_words);
            print_r(count($useful_words));

            //echo '<pre>';
            $index = array_count_values($useful_words);
            arsort($index, SORT_NUMERIC);
            //print_r($index);
            //echo '</pre>';

            return $index;
        }
       // $file1 = indexFile ('airlines.txt'); //array
       // $file2 = indexFile ('africa.txt');  //array

        function merge_common_keys(){
            $arr = func_get_args();
            $num = func_num_args();

            $keys = array();
            $i = 0;
            for($i=0;$i<$num;++$i){
                $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($arr[$i]));
            }
            $keys = array_unique($keys);

            $merged = array();

            foreach($keys as $key){
                $merged[$key] = array();
                for($i=0;$i<$num;++$i){
                    $merged[$key][] = isset($arr[$i][$key])?$arr[$i][$key]:null;
                }
            }
            return $merged;
        }


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fileList); $i++) {
        $fileArray[$i] = indexFile($fileList[$i]);
    }

        $merged = call_user_func_array('merge_common_keys',$fileArray);

        $searchQ = $merged[$searchWord];
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($searchQ);
        echo '</pre>';


        //echo "hello2";
    $maxValue = 0;
    $num_docs = 0;
    $docID = array();
    $n = count($searchQ);
    for ($i=0 ; $i < $n ; $i++) {
        if ($searchQ[$i] > $maxValue) {
            $maxValue = $searchQ[$i];
            unset($docID);
            $docID[] = $i;
            //print_r(count($fileArray[$i]));
        }
        else if($searchQ[$i] == $maxValue){
            $docID[] = $i;
        }
        if (!empty($searchQ[$i])) {
            $num_docs++;
        }
    }
    print_r($n);
    print_r($num_docs);
      print_r($docID);
      if(is_array($docID)){
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($docID); $i++) {
            if ($maxValue == 1){$plural = '';}else{$plural = 's';}
            print_r ('<p><b>'.$searchWord . '</b> found in document <a href="'.$fileList[$docID[$i]].'">'.$fileList[$docID[$i]].'</a> '.$maxValue.' time'.$plural.'.</p>');
            $TF = $maxValue;
            //$TF2 = 1 + log($TF);
            echo "<br>$TF2<br>"; 
            $DF = $num_docs;
            $Non = $n / $num_docs;
            //echo "$Non";
            $IDF = (float) log10($Non);
            $TFxIDF = $TF2 * $IDF;
            //echo "$TFxIDF";
         }
      }


//1,2

//file_put_contents("demo2.txt", implode(" ", $useful_words));
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $endtime = microtime();
    $endarray = explode(" ", $endtime);
    $endtime = $endarray[1] + $endarray[0];
    $totaltime = $endtime - $starttime; 
    $totaltime = round($totaltime,5);
    echo "<div id='timetaken'><p>This page loaded in $totaltime seconds.</p></div>";
}
?>
    </div><!-- close wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clean up your formatting, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_word_count](http://php.net/str_word_count) to calculate the number of words.

Comment: ok but i cannot access the array containing the number of words ($useful_words) as it is within a function which is already returning another variable....

Comment: Use `$words = str_word_count($text, 1);`. It will contain all the words in $text. Then you can `array_diff` and `count` as you wish.